# How to optimize EF query?

Tags: sql, performance, entity-framework, asp.net-core, query-optimization

I have a query that returns 31,000 records but works very slowly with EF. I want to optimize this query. How should I optimize it?

```
 [HttpGet]
public IActionResult SearchInTaminJobs(string term)
{
    
    var query = _context.TaminJobs.Where(Ad => Ad.jobName.Contains(term)).Select(c => 
    c.jobName + c.jobCode).ToList();

        return Ok(query);
 
}
```

This query that I wrote goes and checks all the database records.But now I want a query to go and get a list of the first 20 records that are similar to jobName and not check all the database records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's not an EF problem. In your query you use `contains` and full table scan, i.e. you go through all records and for each record you check whether `jobname` contains a text fragment. And since it's a `contains` check you can't just build an index on this column. So your query is just slow. Also you return many records, which can make a contribution into the execution time too. Try to add more filtering before doing `contains` (by some indexed `id` or similar).

To be sure that your query is slow run this raw sql query in SSMS: `select jobName + jobCode from TaminJobs where jobName like '%YOUR_TERM_HERE%'`.

You can also try to limit the number of records which will be returned: `_context.TaminJobs.Where(Ad => Ad.jobName.Contains(term)).Take(20)`

Comment: so How should I optimize it?

Comment: How long sql query is executed? Also try this `Try to add more filtering before doing contains`

Comment: If the table is big and you really want to filter by `%SOMETHING%` without any other filtering (i.e. you can't narrow the area of scanning and indexing of `jobName` will not help you), you can `1.` load entire table into the application memory and then do filtering `2.` or do some FTS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15 which is probably overkill for your case

Comment: I have an idea but I do not know the code, you can help me? This query that I wrote goes and checks all the database records.But now I want a query to go and get a list of the first 20 records that are similar to jobName and not check all the database records

Comment: try this `_context.TaminJobs.Where(Ad => Ad.jobName.Contains(term)).Take(20)`

Comment: mtkachenko Thank you very much, the problem was solved

Comment: @sadeghfarest I've added the final solution into my answer, so you can mark it as correct.